# Can the APA references section be broken down into subsections?

Tags: formatting, references

I'm writing an article and it's time for references. The problem is it needs to be APA style in alphabetical order. There are so many references, I'd like to put them in sections. Is that acceptable for a journal?

Example

**Book
references**

**Movie
references**

**Background
references**

**Blog article
references**

**News coverage
references**

Comment: You need to look for official guidance from APA. You could also check what other authors have done when they published similar documents in the same place.